# uniimageview not updating after views tranistion

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview

I have one main view where I display an image, in the method viewDidLoad:

ballRect = CGRectMake(posBallX, 144, 32.0f, 32.0f);
 theBall = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ballRect];
 [theBall setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"]];
 [self.view addSubview:theBall];
 [laPalla release];

Obviously, the value of posBallX is defined and then update via a custom method call many times in the same class.

```
theBall.frame = CGRectMake(posBallX, 144, 32, 32);
```

Everything works, but when I go to another view with

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewTwo animated:YES];
```

and come back with

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewOne animated:YES];
```

the image is displayed correctly after the method viewDidLoad is called (I retrieve the values with NSUserDefaults) but no more in the second method. In the NSLog I can even see the new posBallX updating correctly, but the Image is simply no more shown... 
The same happens with a Label as well, which should print the value of posBallX.

So, things are just not working if I come back to the viewOne from the viewTwo... Any idea???????

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to switch back to viewOne from viewTwo instead of trying to present viewOne modally.

Also note that `viewDidLoad` is called only once - after the view controller's view is loaded into memory.  If you want to perform an action once a view comes back on screen, you should do so in `viewWillAppear:`.

Both of these points are discussed in the UIViewController class reference and in the View Controller Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks! Today I give your solution a try and let you know. You were very very kind! 
However... I'm wondering why the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated should work and the one I use not. I will read again the docs. 
Using [self presentModalViewController:viewOne animated:YES] to go back to the first, viewDidLoad is called again. But more logical is viewWillAppear method... 
I let you know! Thanks!

Comment: When you show viewOne modally the second time, you've got two copies of viewOne in the view hierarchy. `viewDidLoad` is called because you've allocated and initialised the view controller a second time. You just need to dismiss viewTwo to return to the original viewOne.